# Firing a projectile in mouse direction in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to fire a projectile in the mouse direction but i am having trouble.
The angles are wrong, and by that I mean it will only go up left or in the top-left corner.

This is my `Gun` class for which I fire the Bullet.

```
package assets;

import Reaper.Game;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gun
{
  public ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
  protected double angle;
  Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
  private BufferedImage image;
  private int centerX = Game.WIDTH / 2;
  private int centerY = Game.HEIGHT;

  public Gun()
  {
    bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    image = null;

    try
    {
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/gun.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public BufferedImage loadImage()
  {
    return image;
  }

  public int getImageWidth()
  {
    return image.getWidth(null);
  }

  public int getImageHeight()
  {
    return image.getHeight(null);
  }

  public void rotate(Graphics g)
  {
    angle = Math.atan2(centerY - mouse.getMouseY(), centerX - mouse.getMouseX()) - Math.PI / 2;

    ((Graphics2D) g).rotate(angle, centerX, centerY);

    g.drawImage(image, Game.WIDTH / 2 - image.getWidth() / 2,
      900 - image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
      null);
  }

  public Image getImage()
  {
    return image;
  }

  public void update()
  {
    shoot();

    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
      Bullet b = bullets.get(i);
      b.update();
    }
  }

  public void shoot()
  {
    if (mouse.mouseB == 1)
    {
      double dx = mouse.getMouseX() - Game.WIDTH / 2;
      double dy = mouse.getMouseY() - Game.HEIGHT / 2;
      double dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      bullets.add(new Bullet(Game.WIDTH / 2, Game.HEIGHT / 2, dir));
      mouse.mouseB = -1;
    }
  }

  public void render(Graphics g)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
      bullets.get(i).render(g);
    }

    rotate(g);
  }
}
```

This is my `Bullet` class:

```
package assets;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Bullet
{
  private double dx, dy;
  private int x, y;
  private double dir;

  private BufferedImage image;

  public Bullet(int x, int y, double angle)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dir = angle;

    image = null;
    try
    {
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/bolt.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dx = Math.cos(dir);
    dy = Math.sin(dir);
  }

  public void update()
  {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    System.out.println("dx : " + dx + "  " + dy);
  }

  public void render(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
  }

  public BufferedImage getImage()
  {
    return image;
  }
}
```

And this is the main `Game` class:

```
package Reaper;

import Reaper.graphics.Screen;
import assets.Gun;
import assets.Mouse;
import gameState.MenuState;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static int WIDTH = 900;
  public static int HEIGHT = 900;

  public static int scale = 3;
  public int frames = 0;
  public int updates = 0;
  private boolean running = false;

  private Thread thread;
  private JFrame frame;

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private Screen screen;
  private Gun gun;
  private MenuState mns;
  private Mouse mouse;

  public Game()
  {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    frame = new JFrame();
    gun = new Gun();
    mns = new MenuState();
    mouse = new Mouse();
    addMouseListener(mouse);
    addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Game game = new Game();

    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    game.strat();
  }

  public void strat()
  {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Reaper");
    thread.start();
  }

  public void stop()
  {
    running = false;

    try
    {
      thread.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60;
    double delta = 0;

    while (running)
    {
      long now = System.nanoTime();

      delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = now;

      while (delta >= 1)
      {
        update();
        updates++;
        delta--;
      }

      render();
      frames++;

      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
      {
        timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        frame.setTitle("Reaper! " + "  |  " + updates + " ups , " + frames + " fps");
        updates = 0;
        frames = 0;
      }
    }

    stop();
  }

  public void update()
  {
    if (mns.play)
    {
      gun.update();
    }
  }

  public void render()
  {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if (bs == null)
    {
      createBufferStrategy(3);
      return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    if (mns.menu)
    {
      mns.draw(g);
    }

    if (mns.play)
    {
      g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      g.drawImage(mns.getImage(), 0, 0, mns.getImageWidth(), mns.getImageHeight(), this);
      gun.render(g);
    }

    if (mns.rules)
    {
      g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    bs.show();
  }
}
```

I know it's very badly coded, and I will try to fix it as much as I can, but I am really stuck on this. Searched around the web, tried some of the solutions but it wont work. I guess I'm doing it wrong by putting methods in wrong places and calling them, I guess.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a small, self-contained version which demonstrates the basic issue. Few people are willing to trawl through all your code for you.

Comment: The relevant code that I see (the bit using `atan2` and later the calculations of dx, dy in bullet's creation) seem fine, so the problem is either with how the mouse position is detected or how you position the bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know it's very badly coded, and I will try to fix it as much as I can, ...

Next time, consider **first** cleaning up the mess and **then** asking the question.

(Are the variables storing the values returned by `getMouseX()` and `getMouseY()` really *static*?)

However, the main reason for the actual problem are the `x` and `y` values in the `Bullet` class:

```
class Bullet
{
  private double dx, dy;
  private int x, y;
  ....

  public void update()
  {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    System.out.println("dx : " + dx + "  " + dy);
  }
  ...
}
```

They are declared as `int` values. Imagine what happens in the `update` method, for example, when `x=0` and `dx = 0.75`: It will compute `0+0.75 = 0.75`, truncate this to be an `int` value, and the result will be `0`.

Thus, the `x` and `y` values will never change, unless the `dx` and `dy` values are `>= 1.0`, respectively.

Just changing the type of `x` and `y` to `double` will solve this. You'll have to add casts in the `render` method accordingly:

```
g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, ...);
```

But you should really **clean this up**.